# Unable to generate FCM Notification in Android App

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging, chat

I need help, I have developed a social based app that has a chat module, user can send and receive messages but I'm not able to generate notifications. When I send a message as a response I get "null" against volley error function, below is my code, as I am using FCM service.

```
private void sendNotification(final String hisId, final String hisName, final String message) {
    DatabaseReference allTokens = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("new").child("Tokens");
    Query query = allTokens.orderByKey().equalTo(hisId);
    query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Token token = ds.getValue(Token.class);
                //(String user, String body, String title, String sent, Integer icon)
                Data data = new Data(myId, hisId + ": " + message, "New Message", hisName, R.drawable.image_icon);
                Sender sender = new Sender(data, token.getToken());

                try {
                    JSONObject senderJSONObject = new JSONObject(new Gson().toJson(sender));
                    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(URL, senderJSONObject,
                            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                                    //response of the request
                                    Log.i("FCM", "onResponseFCM:" + response.toString());
                                }
                            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            Log.i("FCM", error.getLocalizedMessage() + error.getNetworkTimeMs());
                            Toast.makeText(ChatActivity.this, "VolleyError: " + error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }) {
                        @Override
                        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                            // Put params
                            Map<String, String> header = new HashMap<>();
                            header.put("content-type", "application/json");
                            header.put("authorization", "key=myKey");
                            return header;

                        }
                    };
                    // add this request to queue
                    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(ChatActivity.this, "FCM Exception: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

Below is the log I got when the message is sent:

```
2020-05-25 10:23:52.509 505-1269/com.aadi.developers.asspass E/Volley: [11326] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 401 for https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
2020-05-25 10:23:53.311 505-1269/com.aadi.developers.asspass E/Volley: [11326] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 401 for https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
2020-05-25 10:23:53.315 505-505/com.aadi.developers.asspass I/FCM: null1901
```

The Firebase Messaging class is:

public class FirebaseMessaging extends FirebaseMessagingService {

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(@NonNull RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

    SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("SP_USER", MODE_PRIVATE);
    String savedCurrentUser = sp.getString("Current_USERID", "None");
    String sent = remoteMessage.getData().get("sent");
    String user = remoteMessage.getData().get("user");

    FirebaseUser fUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    if (fUser != null && sent.equals(fUser.getUid())) {
        if (!savedCurrentUser.equals(user)) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                sendOreoAndAboveNotification(remoteMessage);
            } else {
                sendNormalNotification(remoteMessage);
            }
        }
    }
}

private void sendNormalNotification(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    String user = remoteMessage.getData().get("user");
    String icon = remoteMessage.getData().get("icon");
    String title = remoteMessage.getData().get("title");
    String body = remoteMessage.getData().get("body");

    RemoteMessage.Notification notification = remoteMessage.getNotification();
    int i = Integer.parseInt(user.replaceAll("[\\D]", ""));
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ChatActivity.class);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("hisId", user);
    intent.putExtras(bundle);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, i, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri defSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(Integer.parseInt(icon))
            .setContentText(body)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    int j = 0;
    if (i > 0) {
        j = 1;
    }
    notificationManager.notify(j, builder.build());
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
private void sendOreoAndAboveNotification(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    String user = "" + remoteMessage.getData().get("user");
    String icon = "" + remoteMessage.getData().get("icon");
    String title = "" + remoteMessage.getData().get("title");
    String body = "" + remoteMessage.getData().get("body");

    RemoteMessage.Notification notification = remoteMessage.getNotification();
    int i = Integer.parseInt(user.replaceAll("[\\D]", ""));
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ChatActivity.class);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("hisId", user);
    intent.putExtras(bundle);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, i, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri defSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    OreoAndOverNotification notification1 = new OreoAndOverNotification(this);
    Notification.Builder builder = notification1.getONotifications(title, body, pIntent, defSoundUri, icon);

    int j = 0;
    if (i > 0) {
        j = 1;
    }
    notification1.getManager().notify(j, builder.build());
}

@Override
public void onNewToken(@NonNull String s) {
    super.onNewToken(s);
    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    if (user != null) {
        updateToken(s);
    }
}

private void updateToken(String tokenRefresh) {
    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Tokens");
    Token token = new Token(tokenRefresh);
    ref.child(user.getUid()).setValue(token);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

well i searched about it a lot, and found the answer, i am now using Strings instead of JSON object: Below method solved my issue.

```
public void send(String sendTo, String title, String body) {
    Log.i("Check", "Sending: \n"+sendTo + "\n" + title + "\n" + body);
    final JSONObject notification = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject notificationBody = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject data = new JSONObject();

    try {
        Log.i("Check", "Enter TRY Block");
        data.put("key", FCM_KEY);
        notificationBody.put("title", title);
        notificationBody.put("body", body);

        notification.put("to", sendTo);
        notification.put("notification", notificationBody);
        notification.put("data", data);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i("Check", "Enter CATCH Block:" + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    StringRequest req = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.i("Check", "Response: " + response);
            Toast.makeText(ChatActivity.this, "Response: " + response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.i("Check", "Error: " + error);
            Toast.makeText(ChatActivity.this, "Error: " + error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }) {


        @Override
        public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
            try {
                return notification.toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("Authorization", "key=" + FCM_KEY);
            params.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
            return params;
        }
    };
    requestQueue.add(req);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**in my case Puttin "key=" before FCM_KEY solved my issue.
also very surely it is main problem. if u get 401 error. I was write like :

```
params.put("Authorization", FCM_KEY);
```

but true solution is:

```
params.put("Authorization","key=" FCM_KEY);
```

**

```
@Override
public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("Authorization", "key=" + FCM_KEY);
    params.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
    return params;
}
```

};